# WPF stop and reverse Storyboard animation when new animation starts

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger, wpf-animation, coloranimation

I have 2 DataTrigger that animates the background color of a button (with reverse), this part works fine.

The problem is that when the 2 triggers are fired in overlapping times, the first trigger fired does not reverse the color, when the second trigger  stops it reverses the color to whatever was the color when the previous animation stopped.

What should I do?

This is the example code:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsUp}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="isDownStoryBoard"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="isUpStoryBoard">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[0].Color" To="#b4e391" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="2x" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[1].Color" To="#61c419" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="2x" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[2].Color" To="#b4e391" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="2x" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[3].Color" To="#b4e391" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="2x" />                           
            </Storyboard>                                                                                                                                     
        </BeginStoryboard>                                                                                                                                    
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>                                                                                                                                                                                   
</DataTrigger>                                                                                                                                                

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDown}" Value="True">                                                                                                         
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="isUpStoryBoard"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="isDownStoryBoard">                                                                                                                                     
                <Storyboard>                                                                                                                                      
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[0].Color" To="#efc5ca" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="2x" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[1].Color" To="#d24b5a" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="2x" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[2].Color" To="#ba2737" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="2x" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[3].Color" To="#f18e99" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="2x" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>     
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`StopStoryboard` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stopstoryboard(v=vs.100).aspx) that you can use to stop a running `Storyboard` with, but there is no `ReverseStoryboard` class. However, you can just create another `Storyboard` that runs in reverse to your original one that you start when you stop the original one. You can use the `StopStoryboard` class like this (from the linked page on MSDN):

```
<!-- Begin the Storyboard -->
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="BeginButton">
  <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryboard">
    <Storyboard >
      <DoubleAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetName="myRectangle" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
        Duration="0:0:5" From="100" To="500" />
    </Storyboard>
  </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>

...

<!-- Stop the Storyboard -->
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="StopButton">
  <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MyBeginStoryboard" />
</EventTrigger>
```

Also, please see the [`Timeline.FillBehavior` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(v=vs.100).aspx) that you can set on the `Storyboard` which *Gets or sets a value that specifies how the Timeline behaves after it reaches the end of its active period.* You can set it to the [`FillBehavior.HoldEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.fillbehavior(v=vs.100).aspx) enumeration to get the `Storyboard` to keep it's last value when it ends.

Comment: Thanks Sheridan. This is nice, but I don't know what was the previous state, that is why I want it to be reversed to whatever the state was when the animation started

Comment: Sorry, but there is no `ReverseStoryboard` class. You could always try to access the `Storyboard` programmatically and alter its properties, but I wouldn't recommend doing that.